# ssis 2012 can't find assemblies

Tags: .net, ssis

I am following this link to use SSIS to load google sheet data into SQL Server
http://www.statslice.com/leveraging-google-docs-with-ssis

I copied the three google dlls into C:\Windows\assembly\ but in the SSIS package, it can't find the assemblies:

The type or namespace name 'Google' can not be found.

I am doing this on windows server 2012, sql server 2012 (SSIS), not sure if other info are needed.

I am a MS BI developer but not having much experience with .net (I have done some coding in SSIS components but not creating or using other assemblies, no may lack some of the background knowledge).

Comment: Did you actually copy them or did you register them "properly." The article notes "That should register the DLL’s automatically, however if you have issues, try a reboot or Google how to manually register a DLL into the GAC."

Comment: Yes you probably have to register them and/or include them as references in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have figured out. I did the registration by copy the three assemblies to the C:\Windows\assembly. What I didn't do was to include the reference to the Google assemblies  in script component c# project.

Answer (score 0):

In the script component script - project - add reference - browse, then locate the assemblies to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Did you registered DLL's like this?

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil" -i google.gdata.client.dll

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil" -i google.gdata.spreadsheets.dll

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil" -i google.gdata.extensions.dll